# Paypal Buy Now does it trigger webhooks of received payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons, paypal-webhooks

Does Paypal "Buy Now" button triggers webhooks?
What's the disadvantage of using the Buy Now button versus a fully integrated payment system in a website selling digital goods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PayPal buttons trigger webhooks called IPN (instant payment notification). You can define a controller to handle this request and update your database.

The button you put on your web site can include custom fields that will be sent back by the IPN (along with all information sent by default, such a price, etc) , making it easier to identify the payment (such as the identifier of the customer in your application).

I can elaborate and add some code later. Unfortunately I’m on my cellphone right now.

I cannot compare to other methods, as I have only worked with PayPal buttons and IPN, but it’s quite easy to make it work.

https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNIntro/

Comment: Hey Pablo, thanks there is no need for code. I just want confirmation that you can effectively build an e-commerce website through it. From my understanding you can have your custom backoffice application (to handle pricing, purchases etc.), then create a form with the "Buy Now" and provide some values (price of the item, name, description, a unique id for my system to recognize the purchase) so that paypal will just sort out the payment and trigger a Payment Notification on my end. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes. You can use buttons created directly on PayPal with their create button feature, or you can create buttons dinamically in your application. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments